# How to use `fetch` API on big file withou using too much memory

Tags: google-chrome, ecmascript-6, webapi

I have a web application which do things below

1. use `fetch` to download a big tgz file (5G or more)
2. use `response.getReader()` to read, decompress, anylyst the data,  while the downloading continue

Quite simple process. However, what i oversed is, if step 2 is slower than step 1, the `fetch` API just eat memory endless. I notice the fetch API sometimes uses 4G memory or more.

So is there anyway to avoid this?

**persudo code likes this**

Let's assume my network download speed is about 50MB/s. But in the `while(true)` loop, the algorithme to handling `value` is only 5MB/s. This makes my memory continously grow up.

```
let response = await fetch(this.url, {responseType: 'blob'})
while (true) {
    const {done, value} = await reader.read()
    /*Do something with value.*/
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of how you are reading from the stream. It should have backpressure.

Comment: well. when i say `step2 is slower than step1`, we can have a extreme experiment to smulate this case.  Just `fetch(url); while(true){}`, you will find the memory continously grow up ulti the chrome crash

Comment: `while(true){}` is a synchronous loop that won't grow memory usage.

Comment: @demonguy It freezes and crashes *because of* `while(true)`. It blocks any other code (even async) from executing. Have you tried without it?

Comment: My code above is just an explanation. My realy code is not like that. I changed my code avoce